# Datatables muestra ultimo registro de un timer countdown

Tags: mysql, ajax, json, datatables

Tengo el siguiente problema que no he logrado solucionar.
Tengo un timer (countdown) que se genera por cada fila del datatables, que vienen de una base de datos. Esto funciona bien, el problema es que en todas las filas, me muestra el ultimo registro correspondiente a la consulta a la base de datos.
En la imagen adjunta, se ve puede ver eso.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la columna tiempo, se repite el registro que es datetime y que es el ultimo de la condicion generada en mysql.

El codigo que genera, esta muestra es el siguiente:

```
{
    "sClass": "alignRight",
    "data": "tiempo",
    'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
        var tiempo = data;
        var splitDate = tiempo.split(" ");
        var date = splitDate[0].split("-");
        var time = splitDate[1].split(":");
        var dd = date[2];
        var mm = date[1]-1;
        var yyyy = date[0];
        var hh = time[0];
        var min = time[1];
        var ss = time[2];

        window.countDownDate = new Date(yyyy, mm, dd, hh, min, ss).getTime();

        var x = setInterval(function() {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var distance = countDownDate - now;
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            document.getElementById("time-"+meta.row).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("time-"+meta.row).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            }
        }, 1000);
        return '<p id="time-'+meta.row+'"></p>';
    }
}
```

La variable tiempo, es la que trae los datos json desde la base de datos que es en formato datetime.

Aqui la consulta mysql:

```
SELECT

permisos_pedidos.tiempo

FROM permisos_pedidos

WHERE permisos_pedidos.id_cliente = '$id_cl' AND permisos_pedidos.id_pedido = permisos_pedidos.id_pedido AND etapa_abierta = 'A'
```

Si alguien, tiene alguna idea o se ha topado con algun problema asi, agradeceria, pudiese orientarme a como resolverlo.
Si falta algo de informacion para aclarar el problema, lo subire sin problema.
Desde ya, muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Si ejecutas la consulta SQL los valores de fecha son los correctos? Y cómo invocas esa función que muestras?

Comment: @JocksanCruz hola, gracias por responder. Efectivamente, la consulta al realizarla en consola, muestra los datos (fechas) correctas, diferentes para cada row generado en datatables. La funcion se invoca al momento que json es devuelto por ajax y su variable es row=['tiempo'].

Comment: Y si pones un ´Console.log("time-"+meta.row)´ te generar valores distintos?

Comment: me muestra:
time-0 <br>
time-1 <br>
y se repite varias veces el mismo valor

Comment: Ahora, si quitas el setInterval y solamente muestra las columnas se muestran como debe de ser?

Comment: @JocksanCruz al quitar el setinterval, no me muestra el countdown, queda en blanco.

Comment: Ok, manda a pintar la diferencia de las fechas, o el registro que viene de la BD. Porque si se pinta bien, es decir, tal como viene de BD tu problema es que el mismo interval se asigna a todos tus campos y tendrías que generar un vector de intervalos y trabajarlos por índices.

Comment: Oka, todo indica que es eso.. como se genera ese vector que mencionas? muchas gracias.

Comment: Se me ocurren un par de maneras, es simple pero lleva su rato. Voy a probar y te comparto si encuentro algo que ayude, porque el vector de intervalos tiene un problema y es recuperar el índice.

Comment: @JocksanCruz muchas gracias estimado. igual estoy buscando soluciones. agradezco tu tiempo y ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Listo, te dejo un ejemplo de cómo lo podrías hacer, claramente tu código es más complejo, pero la idea es que tengas una base:

```js
// Vector de tiempos
var tiempos = [];
// datos para prueba
var data = {"employees":[
    { "firstName":"John", "age":5 },
    { "firstName":"Anna", "age":10 },
    { "firstName":"Peter", "age":15 }
]};

// ciclo para agregar los HTML, se crea llena el vector
$.each( data.employees, function( i, value ) {
  $("#personas").append("<p>" + value.firstName + ": <span id='tiempoId" + i + "'>" + value.age + "</p>");
 tiempos.push(value.age);
});

// Boton para iniciar el intervalo
var button = $("button");
button.on("click", function(){
  setInterval(function() {validarTiempos()}, 1000);
})


// VALIDA LOS ITEMS EN 0
// --------------------------
// 1. Cada llamado resta 1 a todos los items
// 2. Actualiza el valor del campo segun el ID
// 2.1 Si es mayor a 0 muestra el valor
// 2.2 Si es 0 marca como "expirado"
function validarTiempos()
{
 //console.log(tiempos);
 tiempos = tiempos.map(x => x - 1);
  
  $.each(tiempos, function( index, value ) {
   if(tiempos[index] > 0)
    $("#tiempoId" + index).html(value);
    else
      $("#tiempoId" + index).html("Exp.");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Personas</p>
  <div id="personas">
  
  </div>
  <button>Iniciar</button>
</div>
```

Ahora, lo podrías aplicar de la siguiente manera:

```
    window.countDownDate = new Date(yyyy, mm, dd, hh, min, ss).getTime();
//-------------
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    tiempos.push(distance);
//-------------
    return '<p id="time-'+meta.row+'">' + distance + '</p>';
```

La idea sería que al terminar la carga de los datos iniciar el interval, con esto deberia funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me queda claro tu ejemplo, no asi la posible integracion a mi codigo. Entiendo tambien, que haces iteraciones en el $.each para cada ciclo recorrido desde el array. Pero mi pregunta radica en como asociar cada iteracion dentro mi funcion.. Si pudieses darme un idea te lo agradeceria mucho. saludos.

Comment: Edit'e la respuesta, prueba a ver que tal. Para esto debes declarar el vector `tiempos`, iniciar el `setInterval` cuando terminas la carga de los datos (o antes no importaría, pues valida sobre el vector) y modificar la función `validarTiempos` de modo haga el cambio de formato a tipo fecha.

Comment: Hice todos los cambios como me mencionaste, pero obtengo un error: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

que lo ubica en la linea $.each( data.tiempo, function( i, value ) {

Comment: @maha1982, declaraste el vector? Tiene que quedar como global `var tiempos = [];`

Comment: Hola, estimado, si, lo declare como global e hice todos los pasos como describiste en la publicacion. de hecho use tu mismo codigo, tal cual, poniendo fecha de prueba, haciendo la conversion de formato y arrojaba el mismo error.

Comment: No tuve resultados positivos, de todas formas agradezco tu ayuda y tiempo. buscare alguna solucion alternativa, ya que el tiempo apremia. saludos y muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: No había notado ese comentario. Tendría que ver el código a ver que pasa. Si lo actualizas?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que deje el codigo tal cual esta en la pregunta inicial jaja.
En todas las modificaciones que hice a mi codigo con tu propuesta, obtenia errores y a veces no mostraba nada. Existe la posibilidad de que me des una idea mas clara de como implementar mas exactamente tu codigo con el mio? Agradecido nuevamente por tu ayuda.